# backbone.js getting data into collection and template

Tags: backbone.js

i am new to backbone.js and need a little help sending data to a template. Im using a model with fetch, and a collection. here is the code :

```
(function($) {

var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/users',
    defaults : {
        name : '',
        email : ''
    },

    initialize : function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.fetch();
    },
    parse : function(res) {
        return JSON.stringify(res);
    },

});

var users_coll = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //model: UserModel
    initialize : function() {
        var u = new UserModel();
        this.model = u;
    }
});

var displayView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {

        this.collection = new users_coll();
        //_.each(this.collection.models, alert);
        //console.log(this.collection);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(this.collection.models));

        this.render();
    },
    render : function() {
        var tmpl = _.template($("#data-display-tpl").html());
        this.$el.html(tmpl);

    }
});

var view = new displayView({
    el : $("#data-display")
});

     })(jQuery);
```

it's working fine upto the model part. In the parse function of the model, i have used console.log() and everything seems fine. i get a properly formated json, and the fetch works fine too.

however in my collection i get nothing when i try console.log(user_coll.models). 
i think i am probably missing something really small. not sure what, maybe the flow of things is all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection's model attribute is meant for specifying what *type* of model the collection will contain and if specified you can pass the collection an array of raw objects and it will add and create them. From the [docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-model)

> Override this property to specify the model class that the collection
>   contains. If defined, you can pass raw attributes objects (and arrays)
>   to add, create, and reset, and the attributes will be converted into a
>   model of the proper type

So when in your code you have

```
  var u = new UserModel();
  this.model = u;
```

You aren't actually adding the model to the collection. Instead you can use the collections [add](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add) or [fetch](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) methods.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to modify your code just a bit to get poin trough...hope it helps clarify few basics.

I also didn't try provided example, but in theory it should work ;)

Here is how his example should be done...
Let's imagine Twitter app for example. Twitter app has only one model that represents one user in system. That's UserModel

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/user',   // this is just for modifying one specific user
    defaults : {
        name : '',
        email : ''
    },
    initialize : function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        //this.fetch();    // WRONG: This call was "wrong" here
                           //        fetch() should be done on Collection not model 
    },
    parse : function(res) {
        return JSON.stringify(res);
    },
});
```

Now, you can have many lists of users on Twitter right. So you have two lists. In one list you have Friends *users*, and in other Family *users*

```
var UsersFriendsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel              // you tell Collection what type ob models it contains
    url: '/users/friends',
    initialize : function() {
        // jabadaba whatever you need here
    }
});

var UsersFamilyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel              // you tell Collection what type ob models it contains
    url: '/users/family',
    initialize : function() {
        // jabadaba whatever you need here
    }
});
```

...

```
var displayView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.collection = new UsersFriendsCollection();
        this.collection.fetch();       // so you call fetch() on Collection, not Model

        console.log(this.collection);  // this should be populated now

        //_.each(this.collection.models, alert);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(this.collection.models));

        this.render();
    },
    render : function() {
        // collection data is avail. in templating engine for iteration now
        var tmpl = _.template($( "#data-display-tpl" ).html(), this.collection);
        this.$el.html(tmpl);
    }
});
```

Comment: one more question here. after 'this.collection.fetch()', i can use console.log(this.collection), navigate using firebug and see my data present in 'models'. but when i try console.log(this.collection.models) it returns an empty object. also getting an empty result with this.collection.toJSON().